# Why is this C function getting linked when it only has a prototype and no code?

Tags: atmelstudio

I have a header file with a function prototype...

```
void setupEntry();
```

That function is called from main() inside a library that gets linked in, but nowhere in the project is that function actually defined.

When I link the project it does not generate an "undefined function" error.

When I look at the .lss output, the function is there and is empty with just a return at the end...

```
void setupEntry() {
     a6e:   08 95           ret
```

Why/how is the compiler or linker creating this empty function out of nothing rather than reporting an error?

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: Quit out and relaod Atmel Studio.

So after spending an hour trying to figure this out, I happened to quit out of Atmel Studio and then reload it... and the problem disappeared. Same exact code and project files, but first build after the reload and the expected error appeared...

```
    libblinkos.a(blinkos.o): In function `run()':
    blinkos.cpp(243,1): error: undefined reference to `setupEntry()'
```

There must be some bug or caching issue in Atmel Studio. I guess the lesson is to quit and reload more often. :/